# Subdivide a bar chart vertically in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart

I am trying to do a stacked bar chart of 4 columns of data.

```
NAME,TYPE,STAGE,VALUE
AAA,typeA,L,25
AAA,typeB,L,25
CCC,NA,L,20
BBB,NA,H,30
AAA,typeA,H,20
AAA,typeB,H,30
CCC,NA,H,20
BBB,NA,H,30
CCC,NA,M,10
DDD,NA,M,70
BBB,NA,M,20
```

I can use the following command and generate a stacked bar chart:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=STAGE, y=VALUE, fill = NAME)) + geom_bar(stat ="identity")
```

[image]

However, instead of having two red rectangles stacked on top of each other representing the type in the 1st column, or 2 red ones in the 2nd column, I would like to divide a single larger rectangle *vertically* based on the "TYPE" column. Something like the following (not to scale!):
[image]
Is this possible with ggplot?

Comment: Do you mean you want to position dodge it? Or do you mean subdivide into blocks of area = to the type subgroup?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have some typos either in your description or your data. Both AAA and BBB are repeated in H; you've assigned TypeA and TypeB to AAA, but your graph suggests moving the bars for BBB around. That said, the horizontal placement of the line segment is going to be challenging.

Comment: @joran Thanks for spotting the typos. I have updated the 2nd figure.